# How to not get the error 'invalid_session_id` from the riotgames auth api?

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch-api

Using the riotgames auth api, I am trying to get my access token using the following request:

```js
await fetch("https://auth.riotgames.com/api/v1/authorization", {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "client_id": "play-valorant-web-prod",
          "nonce": "1",
          "redirect_uri": "https://playvalorant.com/opt_in",
          "response_type": "token id_token",
          })
        });
    let data = await fetch("https://auth.riotgames.com/api/v1/authorization", {
      method: "PUT",
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "type": "auth",
          "username": this._username,
          "password": this._password,
          })
        });

    let json = await data.json();
```

But the response is:
`{ type: 'error', error: 'invalid_session_id', country: 'usa' }`

I've made sure the username & password are correct, and I've tried changing credentials to `same-origin`. It doesn't change anything.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

i think i had the solution,

try that between the two requests

```
  var cookie = result.headers.getSetCookie()
  cookie = cookie.map((item) => {
    return item.split(";")[0]
  }).join("; ")
```

My request worked in postman and not in my nodejs application. so i compared the two requests and i noteced that my nodejs application didn't send the same cookie as Postman with Credential: "include".

so i tried the extract the cookie, concat it to a string and send it to the endpoint

here is my code

```
  //get cookie
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    //Credential: "include",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: '{"client_id":"play-valorant-web-prod","nonce":"1","redirect_uri":"https://playvalorant.com/opt_in","response_type":"token id_token"}'
  };    

  var result:Response = await fetch("https://auth.riotgames.com/api/v1/authorization", options)
  //console.log(result)
  var cookie = result.headers.getSetCookie()
  cookie = cookie.map((item) => {
    return item.split(";")[0]
  }).join("; ")
  console.log(cookie)

  options = {
    method: 'PUT',
    //Credential: "include",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Cookie': cookie
    },
    body : JSON.stringify({
      type: "auth",
      username: "****",
      password: "*****",
      remember: true,
      language: "de_DE",
    })
  }
  var loginResult:Response = await fetch("https://auth.riotgames.com/api/v1/authorization", options)
  console.log(await loginResult)
```